# Authentication tag lengths of AES-CCM in TLS

Tags: tls, aes

I'm catching up on understanding some of the new cipher suites that are appearing in TLSv1.2 and will be making an appearance in 1.3.

While looking through AES-CCM, I discovered that it offers a choice of tag lengths. For example, `TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_CCM_8` offers an an 8 octet authentication tag, while `TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_CCM` uses 16.

Under what circumstances would a client prefer a suite using an 8 octet tag over 16? Why might a server prefer prioritizing a 8 octet tag over 16?

If this comes down to "performance vs. security" how can I measure and decide if the security is worth the cost of performance?

Comment: In this case, overhead is really what matters, total packet size. Small low latency packets may do just fine with 8 octet tags